# how to use javascript to call google map specific location

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Suppose I have a html including 2 `<div>`, one is Google Maps, one is a list
Of course, the maps `<div>` is displaying the map
the list `<div>` is is th2 location list(e.g New York, London, etc)
I have one question, How can I click on one location of the list, and then the Maps will go to the specific location?
When onClick the list item, is it use javascript to call Or How can I do such function using Javascript?

Comment: Good question! Hope you like my answer. It was a good challenge.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using a little bit of jquery to select the elements, call the click function, and get the address from the title attribute.

Check out this jsfiddle for reference:

http://jsfiddle.net/X5r8r/263/

```
<a class="location" title="New York, NY">New York</a>
<a class="location" title="Los Angeles, CA">Los Angeles</a>
<a class="location" title="Washington District of Columbia">Washington</a>

<div id="map-canvas" title="1600 Washington"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

var geocoder;
var map;
function initialize() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(0,0);
    var myOptions = {
         zoom: 17,
          center: latlng,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), myOptions);
}

function codeAddress(element) {
    var address = element.attr('title');
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                   map: map,
                   position: results[0].geometry.location
            });
        } else {
            alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $map = $('#map-canvas');

    initialize();
    codeAddress($map);

    $('.location').click(function(){
        $me = $(this);
        codeAddress($me);
    });
});
```

Comment: This answer uses the Google Maps API V3, which is the right version

Comment: thx for your answer, you are right！now I am wondering if I can use this techniques in flex or other application that the webview  displaying maps, and the list is not in webview, is in native list. is there any methods to use jquery or JavaScript to call the maps

Comment: I'm not familiar at all with flex, sorry. But if the answers right... you should accept it :)